# Grant permissions to a service launched with ADB?

Tags: adb, permissions, accessibility, services

I'm trying to get a simple accessibility service, like Google's Voice Access or Button Mapper to work on an LG Exalt LTE, running a stripped down version of Marshmellow.
The stock is missing many UI components, including system Accessibility Settings, which are normally used for turning accessibility services on or off.
I would like to know if it is possible to compensate for lack of UI with ADB.
I've tried the following:
Install the app (Take Button Mapper for example),
Its manifest declares a few permissions, that i've granted, say:

`<uses-permission name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />`

was granted
`adb shell pm grant package.name.here android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`

I even gave it
`android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`

even though its not declared in the permissions list in the top of the manifest.
I get this error:
`Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package package.name.here has not requested permission android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`

However, It is declared in the manifest here though:

```
<service name="a.i" permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" stopWithTask="true">
  <meta-data name="android.accessibilityservice" resource="res/xml/accessibility.xml" />
  <intent-filter>
    <action name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and thats where the problem is.
this is the service itself, and it requires a non-package-wide permission, `BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`.

if I start it with ADB like this
`adb shell am startservice -n package.name.here/a.i`

I get and error
`Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`

even though I already granted the permission to the package.

I've even tried `adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services package.name.here/.a.i`, but still get the same error.

## Bottom line:

How do I start a service and grant permissions to that service with ADB? To be clear. I already know that I can use `adb shell pm grant` to grant a permission to the whole package, but in this case it is a permission not required by the whole package it is declared in a specific component and I am at loss as to how to launch the component with the permissions it requires through ADB.

Comment: obviously, i used the real package name in place of package.name.here... lol

Comment: BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE is a permission with signature protection level which means it cannot be granted using `pm` like permissions with dangerous protection level. But it can be granted to packages asking for it using: `appops set <pkg> BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE allow`. If only a component (service) is asking for it, what you mentioned should work: `settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services <pkg1>/<service 1>:<pkg2>/<service2>:...`. That's what happens when you allow apps from GUI settings.

Comment: Try killing app process after granting permission. Also AFAIK service should be exported in Manifest to launch it from ADB or by other apps.

Comment: @IrfanLatif heres the cmd output:  `$ adb shell am kill flar2.homebutton  
$ adb shell appops set flar2.homebutton BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE allow
Error: Unknown operation string: BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE
$ adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services flar2.homebutton/a.i
$ adb shell am startservice -n flar2.homebutton/a.i
Starting service: Intent { cmp=flar2.homebutton/a.i }
Error: Requires permission android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I figured it out.
I'll use Voice Access as the example app.

```
adb shell am startservice com.android.cts.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess/com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess.JustSpeakService
```

Next

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.cts.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess/com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess.JustSpeakService
```

Then

```
adb shell settings put secure accessibility_enabled 1
```

Then finally delete the the readout app, to avoid the accessibility features from being overwritten

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.lge.voicecommand
```

I don't think there should be any errors after that, leave a comment if there are though.

Comment: If you want to enable another accessibility service, just rewrite step 2 to a list of all the services, with a colon between them. Like so `adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services pkg1/serv1:pkg2/serv2`